# FSlightbox when opening first time throws: Cannot read property 'zero' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React component that renders the [Lightbox](https://fslightbox.com/react) when clicking on an image from gallery page. And seems to work fine overall, but I found a weird behavior, when I clean all my application site data and go the frist time on the gallery page and click an image I get the next error:

> error: uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'zero' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'zero' of undefined

> react-hot-loader.development.js:294 TypeError: Cannot read property 'zero' of undefined
> at t.r.runActions (pathToProject/node_modules/fslightbox-react/index.js:1)
> at callCallback (pathToProject/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12490)
> at commitUpdateQueue (pathToProject/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12511)
> at commitLifeCycles (pathToProject/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19858)
> at commitLayoutEffects (pathToProject/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22803)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (pathToProject/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (pathToProject/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (pathToProject/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292)
> at commitRootImpl (pathToProject/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22541)
> at unstable_runWithPriority (pathToProject/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653)

Here is my react component:

```
const Lightbox = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { items } = useSelector(state => state.items);
  const { lightboxDialog } = useSelector(state => state.window);
  const sources =
    items?.length > 0 ? items.map(item => item.original) : []; // creates an array of strings with url sources to the images

  return (
      <FsLightbox
        toggler={lightboxDialog?.toggler}
        sources={sources}
        slide={lightboxDialog.slide}
      />
  );
};
```

Has anyone had this problem before? How do I fix it since even the stack-trace is pretty hard to follow

Answer (score 2):

This occurred for me because the `sources` property is not reactive as documented [here](https://github.com/banthagroup/fslightbox-react/issues/99). The documented fix is to add the `key` property to the `FsLightbox` element, since the element will be remounted when the `key` property is changed.

For this particular scenario, I suspect that setting `key` to `sources.length` should address the issue, as follows:

```
<FsLightbox
  toggler={lightboxDialog?.toggler}
  sources={sources}
  slide={lightboxDialog.slide}
  key={sources.length}
/>
```